# Слово "ящер"

Tags: этимология

Какова этимология слова "ящер" и, соответственно, "ящерица"? И кого называли ящерами, если о динозаврах во времена образования этого слова еще не знали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово **ящерица** имеет общеславянское происхождение. Соврем. его форма возникла в др.-рус. яз. благодаря присоединению суф. имен женского рода -иц-а к основе имени мужского рода *ящеръ* (со значением «ящерица», «небольшое животн. класса пресмыкающихся с длинным 
хвостом»), отмечаемого в памятниках XIV в. Глубокая история слова **ящеръ** достоверно не изучена. Обычно считается, что оно развилось вследствие йотации более стар. *aščerъ>, образованного присоединением прист.* а- *с неизвестным знач. к основе* sker-, в которой перед *е* сочетание *sk* дало ш'ч (щ). Сама основа *sker- имеет двоякое объяснение. Одни считают, что она представляет собой звуков. разновидность основы* скор- *(ср. скорый). Следоват., животн. названо по той примете, что быстро бегает.  Другие связывают основу* sker- со словом *скора* «шкура» (ср. кора, скорняк). В таком случае ящерица — букв. «животное, меняющее шкуру, кожу». Ср. диал. *ящер* «шершавая кожа», «шагрень» и *ящер* «шероховатое воспаление языка, рак языка у лошадей, коров», «то же, что ящур».